# Сугубо - русизм чи питоме слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм

Сьогодні виникла у мене доволі цікава ситуація. Читала книжечку ***Кубіцького С.О. Технології соціально-педагогічної роботи в зарубіжних країнах***. Там натрапила на таке речення:

> Професія соціального працівника в Німеччині виникла на початку XX ст.
>   як **сугубо** жіноча.

До сьогодні думала, що це русизм і навіть деяких людей правила. Однак все щось захотілося переконатися у правильності своїх думок. Зайшла у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/sughubyj), а там пише:

> **СУГУ́БИЙ**, а, е. Особливий, винятковий.

Проте [Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) містить це слово і подає українські відповідники:

> **Сугубый** – подві́йний, ***особли́вий***; -**бо** – подві́йно, ***особли́во***.

Виникає подвійна ситуація: СУМ подає, що це питоме слово без жодних приміток; російсько-український словник - що це російське слово і наводить відповідник *особливо*.

Отже, слово **сугубо - русизм чи питоме**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9) знаходимо (*зверніть увагу на позначку **книжн. заст***.) :

> НАДЗВИЧА́ЙНИЙ (дуже великий за силою вияву, інтенсивністю чого-небудь, завдяки чому виділяється на загальному тлі), НЕЗВИЧА́ЙНИЙ, ВИНЯТКО́ВИЙ, **СУГУ́БИЙ** **книжн. заст.**

[Т.Ф. Ефремова Новый словарь русского языка. Толково- словообразовательный](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-105962.htm) як і [СУМ-11](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-84026.htm) подає  у словниковій статті:

> **СУГУБЫЙ** сугу́бый
>   **прил. устар.**
>
> 1) Значительно превосходящий что-л. обычное.
>
> 2) Особенный, исключительный (по сравнению с чем-л. обычным).

Як і український словник, так і російський подає **сугубо** як застаріле слово. Отже, це слово є *старослов’янізмом*.

У [Cловнику старослов’янських слів](http://uk.shram.kiev.ua/fun/slovar-staroslavianckih-slov.shtml) знаходимо:

> **СУГУБЫЙ** - двойной, удвоенный

У зв’язку з історичними умовами творення обох мов, старослов’янська мала вплив і на українську і на російську мови [Іван Огієнко Історія української літературної мови](http://litopys.org.ua/ohukr/ohu.htm). І  в російській і в українській мові слово **сугубо** починає втрачати нормативність. Підтвердження цього знаходимо в [Уроках державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик»)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53409/27037.html):

> **СУГУБО** 
>   правильніше: суто

Отже, слово **сугубо** не є русизмом, а старослов’янізмом, яке, в зв’язку з розвитком мови, знайшло більш нормативні відповідники і потрохи починає витіснятися з нормативної української мови.